# ESB Volume partition limited to 2TB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I created an instance via AWS Ruby SDK v1 with this mapping:

```
block_device_mappings: [{
  device_name: '/dev/sda1',
    ebs: {
      volume_size: 3000,
      delete_on_termination: true,
      volume_type: 'gp2',
    },
 }],
```

I get a 3TB disk but the partition on it is limited to 2TB.

Tried fixing it with `parted` but got:

```
Error: partition length of 6291439935 sectors exceeds the msdos-partition-table-imposed maximum of 4294967295
```

Gave up, don't care how you fix this. But I do want to fix my API call to AWS so this does not happen again. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
API call is fine. Partitioning table is defined by AMI. So the only thing you can do is replace ImageId with AMI that's built on GPT.

If you want to use the whole disk after creating if from AMI that uses MBR partition table, you will need to repartition your disk with GUID Partition Table (GPT). An old-style MSDOS partition table cannot address more than 512*2^32 bytes.

```
sudo parted
(parted) select /dev/xvdX
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) mkpart primary 0% 100%
(parted) quit
```

And the official guide suggests that you skip creation of partition table altogether and just format the whole block device: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html#using-ebs-volume-linux

Comment: What OP didn't directly mention is that this is the boot volume (`/dev/sda1`).  Resizing it using the above isn't necessarily going to work and of course, using the entire block device -- an excellent idea for all other volumes -- won't work, here, afaik.

Comment: Thank, but I don't want to know how to fix this disk, just how to fix the API call. I don't specify anything about partitions in the call. Can't find anything about that in the docs either.

Comment: API call is fine. Partitioning table is defined by AMI. So the only thing you can do is replace `ImageId` with AMI that's built on GPT.

Comment: I changed my answer above.